# How to change sap.m.Select binding?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

`<Input value="{binding}"/>` works fine.

But if I use

`<Select>
    <core:Item key="{key}" text="{binding}" />
    <core:Item key="1" text="O530" />
    <core:Item key="2" text="O531" />
</Select>`

It shows like

`<Select>
    <core:Item key="1" text="O530" />
    <core:Item key="1" text="O530" />
    <core:Item key="2" text="O531" />
</Select>`

But what I want is

`<Select>
    <core:Item key="1" text="O530" /> (selected)
    <core:Item key="2" text="O531" />
</Select>`

What should I do ？

I tried to use `setSelectedItem`, but I used `form.bindElement("/ProductSet('1')")` in controller, I don't know how to get the    `{binding}` out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why have you used:

```
<Select>
    <core:Item key="{key}" text="{binding}" /> <- This line of code?
    <core:Item key="1" text="O530" />
    <core:Item key="2" text="O531" />
</Select>
```

Anyways, this is how I will do it :
First my model which has the selected key :

```
var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
                  data: [
                         {
                             key:'2',
                             text:'text'
                         }] 
               });
```

Next, my sap.m.select in view : ( I know I have only 2 items for my select so hard code else I will use aggregation binding for sap.m.select) :

```
<Select selectedKey="{key}" id='idSelect'>
            <core:Item key="1" text="O530" /> 
            <core:Item key="2" text="O531" />
        </Select>
```

Here, selectedkey will set the key stored in my model.

Next, element binding from my JSON Model in controller :

```
this.getView().byId('idSelect').setModel(model).bindElement({
                      path: '/data/' + 0
                   });
```

and binding works properly. You can change the key in JSON model and corresponding key is selected in sap.m.Select.

Comment: Thanks,  I solved my problem by using `setSelectedKey`

Comment: @TinaChen, how do you managed to pass binding via `setSelectedKey` method?